# Docx/Pdf/etc and WebView

Tags: android, pdf, base64, android-webview, doc

How I can laod doc/docx/pdf and xls files into WebView?

I tried to use loadData(myBase64, "mime type for example application/pdf", "base64), I tried to use loadUrl("file///...") - no effect. 
Or how I can view this files in my application? (without external programs)

...And I CAN'T to use web readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can laod doc/docx/pdf and xls files into WebView?

You don't. `WebView` does not have the ability to display these file types. `WebView` handles HTML, CSS, JS, some image formats, and the like.

> Or how I can view this files in my application? (without external programs)

You spend a lot of money on libraries to do this.

Comment: docx4j is a free library, and it can convert files into html to display in a webview.